# Problems for install and open node red

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, plugins, node-red

my question is something complicated i think. I started a class about IoF and i was recomended to get Node red.

I used this video for do it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TbXU3PRDN1w
It s some old but i followed the order. I installed node.js, all ok and Windows Shell did all correctly except some about chocolatey, which said me than didnt upgrade. Although, it finished the install and open CA. I had an errors to write the pass to install, but is supossed it hadnt problems. I put pnm install pnm -global (all ok) and then i write
npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-red

And here always give me the same message

```
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated bcrypt@3.0.6: versions < v5.0.0 do not handle NUL in passwords properly
npm WARN deprecated bcrypt@3.0.8: versions < v5.0.0 do not handle NUL in passwords properly
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.12.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.14.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future

changed 362 packages, and audited 363 packages in 3m

7 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

4 moderate severity vulnerabilities
```

I dont know why this happen. I revise about @mapbox- node pre gyp, which i put to upgrade this trouble, nothing

About the library, i read than https://github.com/artilleryio/artillery/issues/895 and https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

I try understand better, but about than i need i dont get anything, and I get stuck here.

Also for close, I open Node red (classmates said me than it do it directly, doesnt matter), and ok, it gives me the link for Node red but when i open the page the plugins get loading and i stay there.

I dont know what to do, or if it s my fault than something is wrong , please if you can help me I aprecciated, I understand very litlle about this and gives headaches.

(PD: Sorry my english if isn t the better, i speak spanish, so if you can respond in spanish, it will more easy for me)

Comment: Answers will always be in English on this site, if you want to ask questions and get answers in Spanish you have to ask on https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

You do nothing about the messages from the install, they are warnings not errors and none of them are critical and all for things that are well understood (mainly down to needing to support old versions of NodeJS until Node-RED v2 ships in a few months).

If you are having problems opening the Node-RED editor in the browser then you need to look at the log from when Node-RED starts and in the browser console. You can ask a new question with those details if needed.